# The meaning of "se les bouffer", and how to use it?

Tags: sens, usage

> Dans les opposants à Céline Pina, on trouve des gens de gauche, y compris du PS, probablement par électoralisme, mais aussi des gens sincères qui croient réellement que les femmes ayant des obligations vestimentaires à cause d'une religion sont opprimées par ceux qui ne veulent pas de ces obligations. **C'est à se les bouffer**, si je puis me permettre.

Given that the phrase is followed by "si je puis me permettre", I assume it is a somewhat vulgar expression.

Incidentally, does the pronoun "les" here refer to something particular, regardless of context? Just like "la (vie)" in the expression "se la couler douce"?

Comment: If I were to use that sentence "C'est à se les bouffer" it would be in a annoying or totally stupid situation. It would imply that "les" means testicles. The whole sentence being (excuse my french) "C'est à se bouffer les couilles". Sorry I understand it is inappropriate but it does explain the case. So if I were in the really annoying situation and for instance I don't see any positive outcome, in despair, I could say that.It would mean the situation is so stupid that a stupid action is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The slang expression *se les bouffer* can be used with two meanings.

In the first one, *les* means the others, the opponent:

> Les anglais, on va se les bouffer.

That means we are going to strongly defeat them, to crush them, figuratively to eat them the cannibal way.

The second one is when you realize you made a big mistake or that you lost something, you reached a non return point so there is nothing to do. You are then alone and ruminate the past. Here *les* means a couple of personal items sometimes called *les bijoux de familles*...

In your sentence, the second meaning is used. *C'est à se les bouffer* means that the situation is so disappointing that there is no hope, the person is upset and has nothing to do outside meditating and settling his nerves.

Comment: Wow, there's much more to this than meets the eye. What is the English equivalent of "C'est à se les bouffer" in its figurative second sense?

Comment: No idea, that would be an interesting question on a English Language site ;-)

Comment: Je me demande si cette expression se rapproche plus de « Quel que soit ce qu’on se tape, on serre les dents et s'en fait une raison par défaut » que de « on se trouve au-delà du point de non-retour » ? "Take it on the chin" ou "grin and bear it", peut-être ?

Comment: *Se faire une raison* oui car c'est le seul choix, il traduit l'impuissance à réagir.

Comment: What do you think of "at the mercy of it all"?

Comment: It sounds a bit literary while *à se les bouffer* is crude slang.

Comment: Peut-être lier ces bijoux à une entrée au [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bijoux_de_famille) qui contient la référence anatomique afin d'être certain que l'apprenant en ait le cœur net ! Merci.

Comment: "X is/would be a kick in the balls" might be the closest expression, after all. ;)

Comment: Anatomically close but the meanings are significantly different.